# Same execution plan but Profiler shows very different duration values

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I have a simple query that is generated från Entity Framework that takes about 55 seconds to complete in an .NET application. When I run the query in SSMS with the same parameters it runs in about 4 seconds.

I'm aware that different set options can generate different query plans. I use Profiler to display "Showplan XML Statistics Profile" and I can verify that the query plans are identical but still Profiler shows very different durations depending on whether the query is run from the application or not. The duration for the slow running query is about 50 seconds.

I have also used DMVs to display execution_count from sys.dm_exec_query_stats to verify that the same query plan is being used in both cases.

The query itself is very simple but it returns almost 100.000 records. If I rewrite the query as a stored procedure it runs fast in both application and SSMS but still using the same simple execution plan.

I would like to understand what causes this behaviour.

-----------Update------------------------------------------

I have been treating this as an Sql Server issue but I'm starting to suspect this could be an application problem.

The application uses a Count on a navigation property that is declared using ICollection.

```
public class Department 
{ 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
} 

and then in the application

var department = getDepartmentById(departmentId);
Assert.IsTrue(department.Courses.Count() > 100000);
```

In the application since Courses is declared using ICollection Linq-to-Object is used instead of LINQ-to-SQL. This means that all rows are fetched and courses are counted in memory.

Is it possible that the application could be the cause of the slow performance. That it fetches the rows in such a way that it actually is SQL Server that has to wait for the application to finish.

That would actually explain a lot.

The examples do not show the actual classes or the actual Linq but they display the same behaviour.